# Launch jQuery timer on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have view with countdown timer

[image]
here is code of countdown timer in View

```
 <div class="timer-div-one"; id="countdown" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;">

    </div>
```

Here is js code for timer

```
   $("#countdown").countdown360({
        radius: 40.5,
        seconds: 30,
        strokeWidth: 7,
        fillStyle: '#ffffff',
        strokeStyle: '#ffcf00',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontColor: '#000000',
        autostart: false,
        onComplete: function() { alert(); }
    }).start();
```

I need to start it when i click "Запись" button

Here is button in view.

```
 <button id="record" class="btn btn-default" style="background: #ffcf00; color: black; height: 40px;text-shadow: none">Запись</button>
```

I try to write code like this. But it not works

```
 $("#record").click(function (){
$("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 40.5,
    seconds: 30,
    strokeWidth: 7,
    fillStyle: '#ffffff',
    strokeStyle: '#ffcf00',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontColor: '#000000',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function() { alert(); }
}).start();});
```

Where is my fault?

**UPDATE**

```
  $(function() {

 $("#record").click(function (){
$("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 40.5,
    seconds: 30,
    strokeWidth: 7,
    fillStyle: '#ffffff',
    strokeStyle: '#ffcf00',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontColor: '#000000',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function() { alert(); }
}).start();});

});
```

Not works and counter not visible.

If I write code like this I will see counter and it works and show alert.

Here is code.

```
 $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 40.5,
    seconds: 30,
    strokeWidth: 7,
    fillStyle: '#ffffff',
    strokeStyle: '#ffcf00',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontColor: '#000000',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function() { alert(); }
}).start();
```

As  Jeremy Thille write about click, Yes I have several clicks on "Запись" and "Остановить" buttons.

Here is code:

```
 record.onclick = function () {

    record.disabled = true;
    navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    }, function (stream) {
        preview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        preview.play();

        // var legalBufferValues = [256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384];
        // sample-rates in at least the range 22050 to 96000.
        recordAudio = RecordRTC(stream, {
            //bufferSize: 16384,
            //sampleRate: 45000,
            onAudioProcessStarted: function () {
                if (!isFirefox) {
                    recordVideo.startRecording();
                }
            }
        });

        if (isFirefox) {
            recordAudio.startRecording();
        }

        if (!isFirefox) {
            recordVideo = RecordRTC(stream, {
                type: 'video'
            });
            recordAudio.startRecording();
        }

        stop.disabled = false;
    }, function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, null, '\t'));
    });
};

var fileName;
stop.onclick = function () {
    record.disabled = false;
    stop.disabled = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = null; //Solve trouble with deleting video
    preview.src = '';

    fileName = Math.round(Math.random() * 99999999) + 99999999;
    console.log(fileName);
    if (!isFirefox) {
        recordAudio.stopRecording(function () {
            PostBlob(recordAudio.getBlob(), 'audio', fileName + '.wav');
        });
    } else {
        recordAudio.stopRecording(function (url) {
            preview.src = url;
            PostBlob(recordAudio.getBlob(), 'video', fileName + '.webm');
        });
    }

    if (!isFirefox) {
        recordVideo.stopRecording(function () {
            PostBlob(recordVideo.getBlob(), 'video', fileName + '.webm');
        });
    }

    deleteFiles.disabled = false;
};
```

I try to paste counter inside Record click, but it not works
Where is my fault?

**UPDATE2**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
>       at Recording:250

Yes it reference to another button, i deleted it.

But I don't see timer anyway.

Comment: what do you get in console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at Recording:249

and my timer become invisible with this code
@MehulMohan

Comment: `<div class="timer-div-one"; >` looks bad. Remove the `;`

Comment: Where is your #record button? Is it dynamically added?

Comment: Nope, It's on View@MehulMohan

Comment: `<button id="record" type="button" ...>` Add type so it does not default to a submit button.

Comment: So did you remove the `;`? I got no feedback.

Comment: Yes< I removed it @JeremyThille

Comment: Are there error messages?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at Recording:254 @epascarello

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countdown360 is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Recording:118)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009) @epascarello

Comment: So than the issue is something else and has nothing to do with the code provided. That means that `countdown360` is not included in the page. Do you have a reference to jQuery library more than once on the page?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` cannot come from jQuery. This comes from elsewhere in your code. You have a `onclick` somewhere.

Comment: I updated my post @JeremyThille

Comment: So now it's pretty clear : "stop" or "record" are undefined, so you can't attach an `.onclick` event to them. You even have the line where the error occurs (250). That's what's blowing up your entire code, and that's why you don't see your timer.

Comment: "stop" or "record" are undefined. Nope , they was defined. Now all ok.@JeremyThille

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

Here is how it need to be done

```
 var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 40.5,
    seconds: 30,
    strokeWidth: 7,
    fillStyle: '#ffffff',
    strokeStyle: '#ffcf00',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontColor: '#000000',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {
        console.log('done');
    }
});


$('#record').click(function () {
    countdown.start();
});
$('#stop').click(function () {
    countdown.stop();
});
```